# Aligning searchbar to the right in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have the searchbar in the bootstrap navbar to be fixed to the right side of the screen or would that go against it's flexibility? I'd like it to stay at the rightmost side of the screen regardless of the amount of links in my navbar. I'm a beginner to both css and bootstrap so I was unsure if I should edit the size in the class section of the element or override it in css. I've managed to modify other aspects of the navbar but I can't seem to move the search bar one bit. I assume it's since d-flex makes it next to the previous element.

```css
#navbarDog{
    background-color: #F5EFE6;
}

#logo{
    height: 100px;
}
.nav-link{
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: font-size 0.4s;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.header-products {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox excersice - Fibonacci Flexbox</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbarDog">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" ><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>                 
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="header-products">
        <h1>Products</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Feel free to purchase one of our t-shirts, your money will go to save even more dogs</p>
    </main>




</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the width of your navbar, just replace `me-auto` with `w-100` and give the search bar `ms-auto` to push it to the right.

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
               .
               .      
               .          
       <form class="d-flex ms-auto">
           <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
```